# form submission not always working

Tags: forms, codeigniter, submission

I'm trying to figure out the problem here and I can't see why its not working.  I've got an edit form that 99% of the time submits fine but for some records it doesn't.  This is some of the code on the form:

```
<?php echo form_open('administration/categories/edit_offer_content_success')?>
<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" class="admin-panel table_style">
<tr>
<th><b>Edit Offer</b><?php echo form_hidden('id',$offer->id)?></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name:<br /><?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'name', 'value' => $offer->name, 'size' => '100'))?></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" height="20"><?php echo form_submit('','Save')?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close()?>
```

When you click on the save button it should go to the edit_offer_contents function but on some records, it goes to the index page of the site instead.  I remmed out all the code in this function and set it to load a debug page instead hoping to track down where the error was occurring, but on the records that won't save, it still goes to the index page of the site so it looks like its not getting to the function but I can't see why.  There is no validation as far as I can see and I'm now banging my head against the wall

```
function edit_offer_content_success()
{
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
$this->load->view('admin/debug');
//  redirect ('administration/categories/edit_offer/'.$id,'refresh');
}
```

if anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful

Comment: can you please share a "non-working"-record. is that behavior reproducible?

Comment: do you have a `__construct` for the class `categories`?

Comment: You have probably an error in your method that is sending $offer object to the view where you have a form. I guess no values are echoed and therefore nothing is send to you success method. Have opend firebug and check always the input elements. If this is not a problem. Then instead of profiler use `var_dump($_POST['name']); die();` and check the results. Btw. why are you not using name for the submit button?

Comment: there is no __construct for the categories class, it extends the Controller class - class Categories extends Controller

Comment: the var_dump won't work because it doesn't go to the debug page for me to check the results. I haven't used name for the submit button because its not my code, I am just trying to debug someone elses code. How it works is, there is a page with a list of records, when you click on a record the code takes you to the edit_offer function of the categories controller:function edit_offer() {
  $this->db->where('id',$this->uri->segment(4));
  $query = $this->db->get('offers');
  $data['offer'] = $query->row();
  $data['url'] = 'editoffer';
  $this->load->view('admin/body',$data);
 }

Comment: the edit_offer function opens that record and shows it on the editoffer view which shows the record with an edit button on the bottom, that button calls the edit_offer_content function <?php echo anchor('administration/categories/edit_offer_content/'.$offer->id, 'edit', array('title' => 'edit', 'style' => 'color:#FF0000'))?>. That function shows all the fields for that record on an editable form which is the one above. When you click on the save button, it should go to the edit_offer_success function

Comment: have just installed firebug and will test with that shortly

Comment: I found a forwarder on the 404 page not found, now when I click on the save button, it takes me to the 404 page not found page. The link it is trying to go to is the exact one it is supposed to be going to.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you have one of the columns set as unique key in the database and sometimes trying to update the values of those columns to some existing values.